# Is Buffalo Drivestation DDR compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: 13.04, hard-drive, compatibility

Please excuse any ignorance on my part, I'm not the most tech savvy.

I purchased a Buffalo Drivestation DDR.  The hard drive says it's compatible with Mac and Windows OS.  Does this mean I am unable to use it with my Ubuntu laptop?

Comment: Try it with an Ubuntu live session?

Answer (score 1):

It should work, though the software they ship with it won't.  The product sounds like snakeoil though so I suggest not touching it with a 10 foot pole.

It claims it has a 1 GB cache and that this makes it super fast, but the OS already caches files, and typically has access to more than 1 GB for that purpose, so caching the data a second time on the drive is pointless.  Worse yet, it sounds like the drive lies to the OS and claims it has written data when it is still sitting in its cache, in order to get great benchmark scores.  If the power goes out though while it is still holding writes in its cache, your filesystem will be corrupted.